# What does ShFileOperation do when the recycle bin is full?

Tags: windows, delphi, recycle-bin

I use this procedure:

```
function MoveToRecycle(sFileName: widestring): Boolean;
var
  fos: TSHFileOpStructW;
begin
  FillChar(fos, SizeOf(fos), 0);
  with fos do
  begin
    wnd := 0;
    wFunc  := FO_DELETE;
    pFrom  := PWideChar(sFileName + #0 + #0);
    pTo := #0 + #0;
    fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY or FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_SILENT;
  end;
  Result := (ShFileOperationW(fos) = 0);
end;
```

What will happen if the recycle bin is full, does it return false or delete file permanently ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces to get it to show up correctly.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the Recycle Bin can be "full".  How does that work?

Comment: By the way - nice function.  Actually good to know how to move to the recycle bin.  I always just used "deletefile" function.

Comment: Mason - you can set the recycle bin to be a "percentage" of your disk drive space.  But we I learned, using this function at least, it never fills up, but instead pushes out the oldest deleted files when there is no more free capacity left.

Comment: By the way, you are triple null-terminating the path. You've got one more null than you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to find out is to actually do it.  Made my recycle bin be minimum 1 percent of drive.  Created a bunch of large files and used your function to move them to recycle bin.

What I am finding out (on XP anyways) is that the function always moves it to the recycle bin; but deletes permanently the oldest deleted file.  So it appears when the recycle bin fills up it employs a "first in - first out" type approach to decide which file to boot out.

I was not able to get the function to return false.  Perhaps creating a file too large for the allocated recycle bin do this.

Comment: If it's so important for your customer to keep the files in their recycle bin, why doesn't he just remove the recycle bin limit?

Comment: He is a regular user, so I guess he doesn't aware about that